# Woocommerce Variant Images & Feature Image issue

Tags: woocommerce

Adding normal product feature image is simple...and working good.

I tried to add variant products and its images ...shows all images on click of variant colors ... works fine ... but when i try to add a feature image along with this ... Feauture image display but overwrites all the variant product image ... and when i try to click on each color no change in variant image.

I want to show main product feature image + variant product images on click on its variant ( color image)

Comment: You just need to add all images to the Product gallery too

Comment: Adding all variant product to Product Gallery? Is it make sense to make feature images ? i m asking because in that case i have to add many images in that.